# Strange use of constructor in C++

Tags: c++, constructor

I'm trying to understand other person's code written in C++, but there is a strange use of constructor  I've never seen. The code looks like this:

```
A* a = new A(some initial values...);
...
B* b = new (a) B(some initial values...);
```

When initializing variable `b` there is `(a)` between `new` and `B(...)`. What does this mean?

Comment: Google "placement new"

Comment: some hairsplitting: this is not the constructors code, but this code is calling the constructor.

Comment: But it looks strange to use placement new on some other class instance - A.

Comment: @MarcinJędrzejewski: It does and this particular code example is buggy, provided in the "..." nothing happens to `a`.

Comment: @phresnel, no, that depends on whether `operator new` is overloaded for those arguments, which you cannot know from what is shown above (and the OP confirms in a comment below that is is overloaded, so no bug here).

Comment: @JonathanWakely: No, it depends on `...`, the second `some initial values...` _and_ whether it is overloaded :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The line of code:

```
B* b = new (a) B(some initial values...);
```

Is using a ["placement new"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Placement_syntax).

The default behavior; it is creating the new object of type `B` in the same memory location as the object `a`. If there are associated overloads for the placement new, then the behavior would be as coded in the overload, which could include some default type behavior as well.

The **code needs to be considered with any overloads**, memory layout of the objects and how the classes `A` and `B` relate to each other.

It is unusual to create an object over the location of a previously created object. I would imagine there is some code between these two presented here that deconstructs (but still leaves the memory "allocated") the previous object `a` before constructing the new one in its place.

The [isocpp FAQ](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/dtors#placement-new) has some further advice on the use of this technique and its dangers.

Comment: then what happens to `a` ? how do they share the same location?

Comment: @Selman22. Depends on what other code there is. Frankly I think the code smells.

Comment: It's not necessarily creating it at the same location, there could be an overload of `operator new(size_t, A*)` which does something completely different (e.g. calls `return a->allocate(sizeof(B))`)

Comment: @Selman22 the object pointed to by `a` ceases to exist. The pointer `a` probably can't be used (but that would depend on exactly what A and B were).. I would guess this code was an attempt to save on memory usage by re-using the space pointed to by `a`

Comment: @JonathanWakely. True that, the overloads introduce a number of alternatives.

Comment: I've looked into the code, there was overloaded `new` as @JonathanWakely said.

Comment: I've seen the pattern used in pre-C++11 code for constructing new objects directly inside a container (remember, push_back copies the object inside the container). Basically, a weird emplace_back

Answer (score 2):

This is so called **placement new** syntax.

Maybe you do not realize this but new behaves mostly as a standard C++ function and thus can be overridden and sometimes may also accept additional parameters. In this case, additional parameter (argument) being passed to the function `new` of class `B` is `a`.

You can read more on this for example [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jaredpar/archive/2007/10/16/c-new-operator-and-placement-new.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

[new expression](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new)

Unless overloaded (in which case it could even format your hard drive), it means *construct `B` at location `a`*, without allocating new memory for its own sake.

Comment: That's what the default placement-new operator does, but this might use an overloaded `operator new(size_t, A*)` that could return some completely different memory location, rather than the same location as `a`.